# Is modifying arrays in multiple functions bad practice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I have an array, which is declared on top of my application:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]
```

And I have two methods running in the background.

Method 1

```
Array.prototype.numberOfCoolElements = function(){
          doSomethings();
          doOtherThings();

          // meantime, the method2 will be called

          return this.length;
}
```

Method 2

```
Array.prototype.changeTheLength = function(){
          this[100] = 123;
}
```

If I am running both methods on two async functions with the same array reference:

Is it possible for the length of the function be changed after `numberOfCoolElements` is called and before it is finished?

Comment: No, javascript is single threaded.

Comment: it depends on which async action gets completed first, before modifying the array

Comment: If I run both on "the same time", in two async functions, is possible for the changeLength to be completed just before the numberOfCoolElements return?

Comment: @AfonsoMatos no, there is only one executing cursor in Javascript. It will call one method and then the other. Which one is called first depends on other things.

Comment: No, it cannot happen, but you might want to consider not at all to pass the same array references into two functions that mutate it. Try to use pure functions instead :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible, as JavaScript has run-to-completion semantics. More information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop.

Relevant quote:

> This offers some nice properties when reasoning about your program, including the fact that whenever a function runs, it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates)